# Conditional compilation: compile once if macro is present at least once

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I'm writing a **C** program and would like to write a function so that, if a certain macro is used *at least once*, the function is compiled in the object file *exactly once*.

I was thinking of something in these lines:

```
#define CERTAIN_MACRO \
    ...some code here... \
    #include "myfunction.h"
```

(adding my function code in myfunction.h, with suitable include guards in order to prevent multiple inclusion), or

```
#define CERTAIN_MACRO \
    ...some code here... \
    #define USE_MY_FUNCTION

#ifdef USE_MY_FUNCTION
    my function code
#endif
```

But neither works, because `#define` and `#include` are not allowed in macro-expanded code. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Suggestion: ask about the problem you're actually trying to solve, there may be some other way of achieving it. For example, if the real objective is that the function isn't present in the binary when it's unused, then marking the function `static` might do the job, because the compiler can remove it if it's unused. But for another example, if there's a `#error` in the function that you want to trigger if and only if the macro is used elsewhere in the file, you're out of luck.

Comment: Don't try to make the compiler do linker's work. Put your function into a separate file, compile it, and build a static library. Let the linker do the rest.

Comment: I think I'll go for a linker-based solution, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let the linker do the job it's meant to.

Place the function into its own source file and then build that into a library, say `liboptional.a`.

When it comes time to create the executable, use that library, for example:

```
gcc -o execfile file1.o file2.o -loptional
```

At the time the linker sees the `-l optional`, it will use the objects within that library to satisfy undefined references. Hence, if you're used the function in `file1.o` or `file2.o`, it will be included.